# Having an image inline with anchor text in list

Tags: html, css

Here's what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/dDK6z/

I have tried things such as `display:inline(-block)` and added margins, padding etc. but none of these move the image down / text up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to vertically align the image?

```css
img { 
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dDK6z/2/).

Comment: Works nicely in the demo, I'll see what it's like in my code.